# Container View Wont Raise

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have some code that is supposed to raise a container view when the keyboard comes in to enter some text. I feel like I have definitely 
implemented this right but the text view is not raising.

```
 var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.title = "Comments"
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "icons8-Back-64"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(GoBack))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton

    self.collectionView?.register(CommentCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)
    collectionView?.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom:-50, right: 0)

    collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: -50, right: 0)
    collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView?.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive

    setupKeyboardObserver()
    view.addSubview(containerView)


    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: containerView)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(48)]", views: containerView)
```

Here im setting the constant to 0

```
    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)


    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

    // Register cell classes
   // self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)
    fetchComments()

}
```

Here im taking control of constant and making it react to the keyboard height

```
func handleKeyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification){
    if let userinfo = notification.userInfo{

        let keyboardFrame = (userinfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue
        bottomConstraint?.constant = -(keyboardFrame?.height)!

        let isKeyboardShowing = notification.name == NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow
        bottomConstraint?.constant = isKeyboardShowing ? CGFloat(-(keyboardFrame?.height)!) : CGFloat(0)

    }
}
```

Despite all this, the keyboard still covers the container view. WHen I change the constant manually it moves but these functions seem to have no effect at dynamically moving the view. I'm confused and any help will be rewarded with a shot at the WWE championship belt. No but seriously I would appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am able to observe from your code is you are managing the scroll top to down and vice versa with single method you just need to do that with individual method one is while keyboard is appear and another one is while the keyboard is dismiss

Here is the sample snippet which may help you

add the different `selector` for each notification

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

Handle the keyboard appear and disappear event with following method

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
                })
            }
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0{
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height 
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note**:
Do not forgot to remove Observer while your view is going to disappear like

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your handleKeyboardNotification function is setting the constant back to 0 in the last line of the function.

Also, your constant shouldn't be negative keyboard value, it should be the height of the keyboard plus a margin if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing bottomConstraint from let to var. Forgot let makes it immutable. Haha guess I'm the WWE champion